# Detech query key with a URL string PHP

Tags: php

I have youtube link

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-Z3RQOTQUg';
```

I easy to get key and value of query string with the script:

```
$url = explode('?', $url);
$url = explode('=', $url[1]);
echo $url[1];
```

But I feel it is crazy and don't optimize.
Have anyone better ways?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If the video id wasn't the first parameter this wouldn't work. Might want to explode on `v=`. Current demo, https://eval.in/438663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything not optimized about your solution. However, if you want an alternative:

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) parses a URL into it's components. One of the component is the query.

[`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) parses a query from a URL, and stores them into an array.

[Now you just combine them.](https://ideone.com/enF3li)

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-Z3RQOTQUg';

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $array);
```